# How to apply object tracking on an object that shows different sides?

Tags: object-detection, yolo, object-tracking

I have been working on a truck detection model using YOLOv4 darknet. The model performance is good. I have applied `deep_sort` object tracking to track the activity of the trucks in that region.

The problem with this approach is that the truck identity changes when it steers around showing a different side against the camera feed or is obstructed by another object.

Is there a way to make sure that truck ID does not change?

[Link to a demo inference video](https://optisolbusinessindia-my.sharepoint.com/:v:/g/personal/abhishek_purandare_optisolbusiness_com/EfaNypjNkKFImw6m_pv3eoQBpAOpfejIbLpPRywQFlMYxQ?e=FlYO3G)

I have trained the model specifically for this video. Object detection works fine but tracking id changes.

Comment: Look into re-identification methods.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong but the re-identification likely won't be useful as vectors for the back and the front side of a truck will be different. Thus, the similarity score will be lower. @B200011011. If you can share any links on this approach. It would be great. Thanks for the response!

Comment: I could not see your video. You can find many resources with re-id on google. You may also want to try different trackers that does allows better tracking under occlusion and perspective change. Someone else may be able to provide better answer.